# Как выключать предыдущий див?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<span onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('hide1'))">Кнопка 1</span>

<div id="hide1">
Блок 1
</div>
```

и

```
<span onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('hide2'))">Кнопка 2</span>

<div id="hide2">
Блок 2
</div>
```

И вот такой JS:

```
function toggle(it)
{
    it.style.display=(it.style.display=="none")?"block":"none";
}
```

Планируется очень много таких кнопков. Как можно реализовать возможность, чтобы при каждом новом открытом div старый выключался?

Comment: храните текущий открытый в отдельной переменной

Comment: по моему правильно писать кнопкоф

Comment: Я только изучаю JS. Подскажите, пожалуйста, код.

Comment: bootstrap collapse юзайте

Comment: bootstrap мне не подойдет к сожалению =(

Comment: как-то так function toggle(it)
{  if (it_last)  it_last.style.display = 'none';
    it.style.display=(it.style.display=="none")?"block":"none"; it_last = it;
}  да, @Grundy забыл дописать var it_last; перед function. Ответ считаю не нужен - задача тривиальная.

Comment: @nick_n_a, главное объявить `it_last` заранее, а то исключение доступа к необъявленной переменной будет внутри `if`

Comment: @Grundy объявление происходит через var?

Comment: @Сергей, да, можно через `var` главное **вне** функции `toggle` чтобы это была глобальная для нее переменная

Comment: Правда в задаче есть глюк, при выключении it их выключится скорее всего два, it и it_last))). Удачи пробуйте.

Comment: @nick_n_a, даже для тривиальных стоит давать ответы. поэтому оформите комментарий как ответ :)

Comment: @nick_n_a, глюка быть не должно, так как с текущим подходом постоянно открытым будет _только один_ элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего так. Таки надо добавлять, что б предыдущий блок прятался если он не текущий, то будет глюк.

```
var it_last;
function toggle(it) { 
    if ((it_last)&&(it!=it_last)) {// скрытие предыдущего
        it_last.style.display = "none"; 
    }

    it.style.display= (it.style.display=="none") ? "block" : "none";  

    it_last = it; 
}
```